# SSRS Report only printing in upper left corner regardless of the pages size

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, printing, ssrs-2008

I have a report that no matter what the page size. It'll only print information in the upper left hand corner. I have the page sizer and all the information within the ruler in the design view as well as having the preferred page size and margins chosen. I am using SSRS 2008. I have reinstalled the printer drivers. The issue only happens in SSRS.

Comment: Go to the Report Property and then adjust your page set up too

Comment: @AnushaSubashini The report properties are set up correctly.

Comment: What happens if you export to another format, PDF for example?

Comment: Exports to PDF work fine. It's just in the SSRS print preview this problem persists.

Comment: Check the page setup of your browser.